# Set is adding duplicated object

Tags: node.js, typescript, set

I'm trying create a set to insert objects avoiding duplicates.

When I do this:

```
const orgs = new Set();

set.add({
org_name: org.org_name,
relation_type: OrganisationRelationType.SELF,
related_org: org.org_name
});

set.add({
org_name: org.org_name,
relation_type: OrganisationRelationType.SELF,
related_org: org.org_name
});
```

I get the following output:

```
Set{
  {
    org_name: org.org_name,
    relation_type: OrganisationRelationType.SELF,
    related_org: org.org_name
  },
  {
    org_name: org.org_name,
    relation_type: OrganisationRelationType.SELF,
    related_org: org.org_name
  }
}
```

Instead of getting this:

```
Set{
  {
    org_name: org.org_name,
    relation_type: OrganisationRelationType.SELF,
    related_org: org.org_name
  }
}
```

How can I add to this Set avoiding duplicates in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid duplications in Set you should take into account [Set equality algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#value_equality)

Please be aware that two literal objects, even if they have same values, are not equal:

```js
{ a: 42 } === { a: 42 } // false
```

Because references are different. However, in case of using references instead of literal objects, such equality will be true:

```
const foo = { a: 42 }

foo === foo // true
```

See this example:

```js
const orgs = new Set();

const obj = {
    org_name: 1,
    relation_type: 2,
    related_org: 3
}

orgs.add(obj);

orgs.add(obj);

orgs.values() // 1
```

If two non primitive values in a set have same reference, second value will not be added